# Display issue on HTC Flyer

Tags: android, resolution

I have developed an application and created the xml files in different layout :

- layout-large
- layout-large-1024x600
- layout-normal
- layout-normal-480x320
- layout-normal-640x360
- layout-normal-640x480
- layout-normal-800x480
- layout-small
- layout-small-320x240
- layout-small-400x240

I have tested the application on five different android devices and it works ok on 4 of it. On the HTC Flyer (resolution 1024x600) the result is not ok. The icon are too little not in the right place...

In the eclipse graphical layout preview of the 1024x600 resolution, the result is ok. I don't understand why the result on the Flyer is not ok.

I have all the image in the drawable-hdpi folder.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I defined the 600x1024 7.0 display as HDPI instead of MDPI. Now it works OK.